# AngularJS and NodeJS required version

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

I am new to the world of Javascript and their frameworks, and I feel a bit lost with this. I am trying to follow the official toutorial of AngularJS. In one of the first sections, it reads

> Install Node.js If you want to run the preconfigured local web-server
>   and the test tools then you will also need Node.js v0.10.27+.
>
> You can download a Node.js installer for your operating system from
>   http://nodejs.org/download/.

The doubt is: **why have I to use `NodeJS 0.10.27`?** it's a old version, given that now (as I've just seen in the NodeJS's website) the project is on the version 4.*/5.*

If I am saying things that aren't, please correct me.

EDIT:

I tried to follow the steps of the tutorial with the 4.* version and I'couldnt due to the required NodeJS version of the dependencies.

Comment: In Node.js v0.10.27+ plus sign means greater than that version. What kind of error do you have?

Answer (score -1):

You can do an installation of NVM (Node Manager Version) and work with any version of node on the same host.

[Repository of NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more, and explain how does this answers the question ?